# CSS Animation & Angular JS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

Fazendo uma pequena aplicação com Angular e Material Design. Para deixar mais *bonitinho* decidi colocar algumas animações simples. A primeira delas é a *SlideInRight* que a tela deveria deslizar para a direita e aparecer na visão; A segunda animação é a *SlideOutRight* que praticamente é igual a primeira, a diferençã é que esta tira da visão.

Meu problema é que quando a outra tela aparece, ao invés de ficar alinhada com a outra, ela aparece em baixo como demostra a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como disse as animações são simples. Abaixo o código CSS utilizado:

```
@keyframes slideInRight {
    from    { transform:translateX(100%); }
    to      { transform: translateX(0); }
}

@keyframes slideOutRight {
    from    { transform:translateX(0); }
    to      { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

.ng-enter { animation: slideInRight 0.5s both ease-in; z-index: 1111; }
.ng-leave { animation: slideOutRight 0.5s both ease-in; z-index: 9999; }
```

Comment: Poderia informar o html também?

Comment: Isso está acontecendo porque o display da div que deveria 'sumir' ainda continua block. Isso quer dizer que ela ainda ocupa todo o eixo Y da página destinado a ela. Para resolver, após o termino da animação passe o display da div para none.